# Best practice for pagination based on item updated time

Tags: api, pagination, api-design

Let's consider I have 30 items in my db. And clientA will make an api call to get the first 10 records based on item updated time. And think of a use case where clientB updated the 11th record (item) by making some changes in it. But now when clientA makes an api call for next set of items  based on the pagination page 2 (items from 11 to 20) It's because the clientB has updated the 11th item the pagination is going to break here (Bases on updated time 11th item will become 1 and 1 become 2, 2 become 3 ...10 becomes 11).There is a chance that clientA is will receive the duplicate data.

Is there any better approach for this kind of problem ??

Any help would be thankfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could retrieve all elements each time using no pagination at all, to prevent this kind of "false information" at your table.

If visualizing the actual values of each record is mandatory, you could always add a new function to your api working as a trigger. Each time a user modifies any record, this api's function will trigger a message for all active sessions to notify the user some data has been changed. As an example, think about something like the "twitter's live feed". In which when a new bunch of tweets are created, Twitter will notify all users to reload the page if they want to see realtime information.